# How can I auto mount an SMB share on KDE + Arch Linux? (re: kio-fuse?)

Tags: kde, fuse, plasma, smb, steam

I'm using a Steam Deck which runs Arch Linux and KDE Plasma.  It has a read-only filesystem (for system files) but does include kio-fuse (5.0.1).

What's the best practice to automatically mount an SMB share in KDE Plasma/Arch Linux?

Do I need to add to the /etc/fstab or is there a better method?  Can the Dolphin file manager automatically add this for me?

Comment: I found that kio-fuse auto mounts the smb drive at `/run/user/1000/kio-fuse-xxxxxx/smb/` once you access any smb file content in Dolphin. I am not sure if it works for Steam Deck but you can try this trick. Note that `1000` is your uid and `xxxxx` is an arbitrary id NOT consistent after reboot. You can also find the mount with `findmnt`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to access the files from dolphin, you can right click (or whatever the steam deck calls right click) in empty space of the places tab -> add entry -> enter smb://*server/directory/*

[image: context menu that shows when right clicking places tab]

If you want other applications to have access to the smb share (e.g., my use case being obsidian note taking syncing my notes), I'm in the process of setting up kiofuse. I currently use this command to mount:

```
dbus-send --session --print-reply --type=method_call \                                         ✔ 
      --dest=org.kde.KIOFuse \
             /org/kde/KIOFuse \
             org.kde.KIOFuse.VFS.mountUrl string:smb://server/directory
```

Still working on an automatic and permanent solution but works for now.
If you go down this route I'd suggest reading the documentation of kiofuse, but I'd avoid it if the dolphin network share works just fine.